# MS Graph Cross-site file copy limit

Tags: microsoft-graph

I am using MS Graph to migrate files and folders from a sharepoint site to a library in another sharepoint site. I call the copy endpoint ok but get the following response for some of the folders that contain larger files:

[403] Cross-site operations cannot be performed on files larger than 50MiB

Is there any way to adjust this limit?

Thanks,